# JS Redirect Not Working but Console Shows No Issues

Tags: javascript, html

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I managed to get this working in PowerApps like a charm but I need a public facing version for a project I am working on which requires a JS function. They are so finicky it seems lol.

Positive that this part of the HTML functions correctly, as no console logs appear and it does the location request as expected:

```js
function fun1() {
  let varGeofenceLon1 = 30.384219;
  let varGeofenceLon2 = 30.248352;
  let varGeofenceLat1 = -97.718391;
  let varGeofenceLat2 = -97.769386;

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    let lon = position.coords.longitude;
    let lat = position.coords.latitude;
    let lontext = lon.toFixed(4);
    let latText = lat.toFixed(4);
  });

  // This part of the function seems to not perform the redirect after the Geofence verification,
  // which I assume has to do with my object utilization here:

  if (
    lonText < varGeofenceLon1 &&
    lonText > varGeofenceLon2 &&
    latText < varGeofenceLat1 &&
    latText > varGeofenceLat2
  ) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.acss.powerappsportals.com/";
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="TestMap.css" </head>

  <body>
    <button class="button" onclick="fun1()">Confirm Location</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also is it possible to pull the coordinates from the console.log by chance? I swear I watched a video that said something about that a while back but I am so rusty with my JS and just need this one thing to work to move on with my life lol.

Comment: What do you mean by "pull the coordinates from the console.log"? I don't think there's any way for JS to read from the console, it can only write to it.

Comment: If you're not being redirected, the condition must be false. Try logging `lonText` and `latText` to see if they're what you expect.

Comment: It would also be best to convert them to numbers before comparing, although I think the automatic conversions should do what you want.

Comment: Okay maybe that is what it was. Either way I just need to retrieve their latitude and longitude values (coordinates) and compare them to the Geofence ranges I established. I feel like this should work but I am within the Geofence range and it is not performing the redirect. The URL is valid as well.

Comment: Two problems:  1)`lonText` and `latText` are local to the callback function, you can't access them in the main function. 2) `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous, you're trying to use the variables before it completes.

Comment: Move the `if` statement into the callback function.

Comment: I don't know why you say there are no console messages. I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: lonText is not defined`

Comment: It was saying that at first but then I edited the function beginning to show "   function fun1() {
  let varGeofenceLon1 = 30.384219;
  let varGeofenceLon2 = 30.248352;
  let varGeofenceLat1 = -97.718391;
  let varGeofenceLat2 = -97.769386;
  let lonText = document.getElementById("longitude");
  let latText = document.getElementById("latitude");" and the issue went away. I assumed that fixed the recognition issue.

Comment: @KaylebPettinger so now you have `latText` pointing to a DOM node (*which does not exist in your example html*) and you are comparing it with numbers. But still the main issue is that the `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous. You will have to move your entire redirection `if (...) {...}` block inside the `getCurrentPosition` callback function.

Comment: If you're getting the values from the DOM, you need to use `.value` to get it from an input.

Comment: Okay so I managed to change the code a bit but the redirect is still not performing as expected. I assume now that the only issue could be that the objects latText and lonText are not the values I expect. Here is the current code just in case the syntax is off:

Comment: function fun1() {
  let varGeofenceLon1 = 30.384219;
  let varGeofenceLon2 = 30.248352;
  let varGeofenceLat1 = -97.718391;
  let varGeofenceLat2 = -97.769386;

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  let lon = position.coords.longitude;
  let lonText = lon.toFixed(4);
  let lat = position.coords.latitude;
  let latText = lat.toFixed(4);
if (
  lonText < varGeofenceLon1 &&
  lonText > varGeofenceLon2 &&
  latText < varGeofenceLat1 &&
  latText > varGeofenceLat2
)
{
  window.location.href = "http://www.acss.powerappsportals.com/";
}}
  }

Comment: Updated the function again to try and just get coords without setting them as variables:   function fun1() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

  let varGeofenceLon1 = 30.384219;
  let varGeofenceLon2 = 30.248352;
  let varGeofenceLat1 = -97.718391;
  let varGeofenceLat2 = -97.769386;

if (
  position.coords.longitude < varGeofenceLon1 &&
  position.coords.longitude > varGeofenceLon2 &&
  position.coords.latitude < varGeofenceLat1 &&
  position.coords.latitude > varGeofenceLat2
)

Comment: No errors so it still has to be a value issue. Not sure how to get the number value of the coords with JS. I feel like this is a much easier issue now though and I can most likely search for that lol.

Comment: I don't know why you are using toFixed.  Try comparing the geoFence with lon and lat directly.

Comment: @James I went ahead and did that and also tried moving the geofence variables to inside the call. That didn't work so I moved them back.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of deliberation I turned this into a code that functions. I imagine I should be within the Geofence but it is still returning a false value, however, this function is working now:

```
  function fun1() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  let varGeofenceLon1 = 30.384219;
  let varGeofenceLon2 = 30.248352;
  let varGeofenceLat1 = -97.718391;
  let varGeofenceLat2 = -97.769386;
  let lon = position.coords.longitude;
  let lat = position.coords.latitude;

  if (
    lon < varGeofenceLon1 &&
    lon > varGeofenceLon2 &&
    lat < varGeofenceLat1 &&
    lat > varGeofenceLat2
  ) {
    window.location.href = "https://www.acss.powerappsportals.com/";
  } else {
    window.location.href = "";
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking Barmar's and other comments into consideration, here is something to try.

First, Barmar noted that javascript will blast on past the `getCurrentPosition()` function before it finishes, and the values will not be available for compare. The solution is to use async/await so that the javascript will wait for the `getCurrentPosition()` function to finish before continuing.

Next, it was noted that the variables inside the `getCurrentPosition()` function are local to that function. The solution is to declare them above the function and merely update the already-existing top-level vars inside the function.

Finally, one of the variables was misspelled: `lontext !== lonText`.

Perhaps this will help?

```js
async function fun1() {
  let lon, lat, lonText, latText;
  let varGeofenceLon1 = 30.384219;
  let varGeofenceLon2 = 30.248352;
  let varGeofenceLat1 = -97.718391;
  let varGeofenceLat2 = -97.769386;

  await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lonText = lon.toFixed(4);
    latText = lat.toFixed(4);
  });

  // This part of the function seems to not perform the redirect after the Geofence verification,
  // which I assume has to do with my object utilization here:

  if (
    lonText < varGeofenceLon1 &&
    lonText > varGeofenceLon2 &&
    latText < varGeofenceLat1 &&
    latText > varGeofenceLat2
  ) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.acss.powerappsportals.com/";
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="TestMap.css" </head>

  <body>
    <button class="button" onclick="fun1()">Confirm Location</button>
  </body>

</html>
```